# Deploy nuxt js project on shared hosting

Tags: apache, deployment, nuxt.js, cpanel, nuxt3

I had a project in which some routes are dynamic. Earlier when I had to deploy the project then what I did that I hit the command "npm run generate" which generates some html files in .output folder and then upload those html files in cpanel's public_html folder. When we simply visits the dynamic page from home page then it works fine but if we reload any dynamic page then it displays 404 error because as such those pages doesn't exists in the public_html folder so how should I deploy my project properly in shared hosting so that I do not have to face this issue. Here is apache server.

Thanks.

I have tried like installing node, nvm and pm2 on live server and then when I try to hit command "npm run build" then it display issue of out of memory something like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGkvU.png)

And then I thought that create build in local server and then upload that build and do some changes in .htaccess file and start pm2 server but it also didn't work.

So please do let me know what I should do required changes so I can create build in live server and then what I should do in .htaccess file and package.json file so that it will work properly